# How to copy similarities between 2 interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have the following structures : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u8c9us

```
  export interface baseStruct {
    code: number;
    message: string;
}

export interface struct1 extends baseStruct {
    struct1: string
}

export interface struct2 extends baseStruct {
    struct2: string
}
```

I create a sturcture1 object, and I would like to create a structure2 object that copy the element of structure1 that are coming from the baseStruct, but remove the rest.

How do I achieve that ?

```
    let newStruct1: struct1 = {
      code: 1,
      message: "hey",
      struct1 : "toto3"
    }

  let newStruct2: struct2 = {
      ...newStruct1,
      struct2: "ho"
  }

  console.log(newStruct2)
```

I want newStruct2 to return

```
{
 code :1
 message: "hey"
 struct2: "ho"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Typescript you are running you can remove some of the casts, in 3.5 value will have a index signature pre 3.5 it will not.

```
function omit<T extends object, K extends Array<keyof T>>(value: T, ...keys: K): Omit<T, K[number]> {
    return Object.keys(value)
        .filter((key) => !keys.includes(key as keyof T))
        .reduce<Omit<T, K[number]>>(
            (obj, key) => {
                return { ...obj, [key]: (value as any)[key] };
            },
            {} as any,
        );
}


let newStruct1: struct1 = {
    code: 1,
    message: "hey",
    struct1 : "toto3"
}
let newStruct2: struct2 = {
    ...omit(newStruct1, "struct1"),
    struct2: "ho"
}

console.log(newStruct2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like copy constructor for a more object oriented way. The below code should work.

```
export abstract class baseStruct {
    code: number;
    message: string;
    constructor(other?: baseStruct) {
        if (other) {
            this.code = other.code;
            this.message = other.message;
        }
    }
}

export class SimpleStruct extends baseStruct { };

export class struct1 extends baseStruct {
    struct1: string
}

export class struct2 extends baseStruct {
    struct2: string
    constructor(other?:struct1) {
        super(other);
    }
}

const b: struct1 = {
    code: 1,
    message: 'Message',
    struct1: 'Struct1'
}

console.log(new struct2(b));
```

Output:

```
struct2 { code: 1, message: 'Message' }
```